# Form validation - if something is false, require this validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, models

In my form validation of my model, I'm trying to say that if the params of a column called `:virtual` is false, then the `:location` field should validate for `:presence => true`.

My current code is:

`validates :location, if :virtual => false, :presence => true`

But that's giving me a syntax error. What's the correct way to format this?

Comment: Did you try following the syntax in the [conditional validation section of the Rails validation guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation)?

Comment: Nope, I did not see that. Thanks.

Comment: Will you add this as an answer so I can give you credit for it please?

Comment: I'd say just take normalocity's answer; it's more complete--I was just hinting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
attr_accessor :virtual  # sets up a "virtual attribute" called "virtual" to which you can read/write a value
                        # this step isn't necessary if you already have an attribute on the model called "virtual"

validates :location, :presence => true, :unless => :virtual?
```

The use of `virtual?` should check whether the attribute `virtual` is true or false. Using `unless` means this validation is only performed if `virtual` is `false` (or is a value that is considered `false`).

More detail on virtual attributes and validation: [Rails: Using form fields that are unassociated with a model in validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327265/rails-using-form-fields-that-are-unassociated-with-a-model-in-validations)

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :location, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |p| p.virtual == false }
```